# WordPress theme error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on a word press theme and every time I try to view the page it comes up with the error message bellow.

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/temp/public_html/natural11/index.php on line 26**

The code of my theme header is as shown bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes() ?>>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>
    <?php wp_title(''); ?>
    <?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' &raquo; SiteRipe Web Solutions'; } ?>
  </title>
  <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building the theme yourself? If so, I suggest you look into this [tutorial](http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/10/how-to-build-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch-part-one/). Judging by the error message, you might be creating the theme in the wrong place.

I have never had problems following those steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign this template to a page before watching it.
I'm guessing you try to watch it directly.

Make a (private) test page, give it this template and then preview that page. It will use this template